# Getting Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x6, while creating permanent delegate

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, token-2022, anchor-spl

My instruction for creating permanent-delegate is

```
invoke(
        &initialize_permanent_delegate(
            &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.mint_account.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.authority.key(),
        )?,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
```

and my account struct is

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: TokenParams)]
pub struct MintToken<'info> {
    /// CHECK: This is the token that we want to mint
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"mint"],
        bump,
        mint::authority = authority,
        mint::freeze_authority = authority,
    )]
    pub mint_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK: the authority of the mint account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(address = Token2022::id())]
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
}
```

but getting `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x6`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize the permanent delegate *before* initializing the mint.

The error that you see `0x6` corresponds to `AlreadyInUse`, which means that it's failing because the mint is already initialized.

You can see the error code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/10d9c63d91bf736387bca8ba5503bf3b3cf425c8/token/program-2022/src/error.rs#L39

Comment: Ya I have resolved it, thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's helpful so that others may find it in the future!

Comment: accepted, thanks Jon